# Why is math.inf a float and why can't I convert it to an integer?

Tags: python, math, infinity

I was doing some experimenting, and I was trying to do this:

```py
import math
for i in range(math.inf):
    print(i)
```

I expected it to be exactly thesame as this:

```py
c = 0
while True:
    print(c)
    c += 1
```

But it went more like this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Then I tried converting the `inf` to an int:

```py
import math
for i in range(int(math.inf)):
    print(i)
```

But that gave me this error saying you can't convert float infinity to an integer.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OverflowError: cannot convert float infinity to integer
```

Now my question is why this happens and why infinity is a float in the first place. Is it because of some underlying mathematical law or is this a solution to some problem that arose from doing it otherwise?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Partly because on traditional platform, an integer can only be as large as the number of bits per registers that are available inside CPUs, thus they overflow.  In terms of data structures, IEEE floats were designed to "represent" inf in a particular way.  However, mathematically, infinity is actually of a different type and thus it isn't a number, so it cannot actually be an integer.  In [this answer I gave in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54849261/2904896), a different user had a similar but different issue to yours which may be of interests.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*infinity is not an integer*.

`math.inf` is equivelent to `float('inf')` and is a floating point feature implemented in compliance of [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) (in addition to `NaN` values and such). From the Python update summaries:

> Many floating-point features were added. The float() function will now
> turn the string nan into an IEEE 754 Not A Number value, and +inf and
> -inf into positive or negative infinity. This works on any platform with IEEE 754 semantics. (Contributed by Christian Heimes; issue
> 1635.)

---

However, if you want to iterate over the natural numbers, you can use a builtin generator in `itertools`, `count`.

```
import itertools
natural_numbers = itertools.count()

for n in natural_numbers:
    ...
```

or you can iterate over ℤ+ with `itertools.count(1)` ;)

Answer (score 3):

`math.inf` is not a specific value; it's a special identifier, more on the order of `nan` than a value.  It is defined as a float for greatest usage in marking a value that requires special treatment.  It's semantic definition is that it's greater than any expressible value: it's *infinity*.  You can't cast it to `int` because there is no defined equivalent.

You *might* want to use the constant `sys.maxint` for your purposes.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860588/maximum-value-for-long-integer) for extra details.

Comment: `math.inf` is a specific value; it is ∞, as specified in the IEEE-754 standard.